# Coordinates Within Draw Method of a Subclass of CCSprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, coordinates, subclass, ccsprite

I am using Cocos2d v2.1.  I subclassed CCSprite and have overwritten the draw method.  I am calling [super draw] so everything with regard to the sprite itself is drawing correctly.

All I want to do at this point is use the draw method to place a red dot directly at the sprites position.  In short, this red dot should appear at the center point of the sprite.  I am using the ccDrawSolidCircle function.

Well, the dot is being drawn, but it is not aligned with the sprite.  As I move the sprite around the screen the dot moves with it.  The further away I am from position 0,0 the further the dot moves away from the sprite.  When I move the sprite to position 0,0 the dot is correctly placed.

Since it was moving this way I assumed this had to do with points versus pixels, thus I multiplied the position of the dot by .5.  This brought the dot closer, but the behavior continued.  I then tried using the convertToNodeSpace and convertToWorldSpace functions, but none of this worked.  But maybe there is some combination of these methods that would work.  Who knows.

I have never had to worry about the coordinates when overriding the draw method of a CCNode subclassed object, but for CCSprite it does not work the same.  This is probably because the draw method of CCNode is empty.

There is probably a simple solution to this, and probably related to openGL coordinates versus cocos2d coordinates, but I am unable to determine this nor can I find something in the various forums.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT 1: Well, I found something that works, but whether this is the best solution I do not know.  I computed a new center position with the following line of code:

```
adjustedPosition = ccp(self.quad.bl.texCoords.u + self.contentSize.width / 2, self.quad.bl.texCoords.v + self.contentSize.height / 2);
```

So far so good.  But if anyone can shed some further light on this, please do so.

Thanks again!

EDIT 2: My draw method code before EDIT 1 was as follows:

```
- (void) draw {
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glLineWidth(1);
    ccDrawColor4B(255, 0, 0, 255);
    ccDrawSolidCircle(ccp(self.position.x, self.position.y), 4, 10);
}
```

After the edit it is now this:

```
- (void) draw {
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glLineWidth(1);
    ccDrawColor4B(255, 0, 0, 255);
    adjustedPosition = ccp(self.quad.bl.texCoords.u + self.contentSize.width / 2, self.quad.bl.texCoords.v + self.contentSize.height / 2);
    ccDrawSolidCircle(ccp(adjustedPosition.x, adjustedPosition.y), 4, 10);
}
```

The "adjustedPosition" code has thus far been working correctly.

Comment: could you post your draw code as it were before the edit?

Comment: See "EDIT 2" in main post.  Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm ccDraw* method coordinates are probably in pixels, not points. Btw, ccp(self.position.x, self.position.y) is equivalent to just using self.position

Comment: LOL!.  Funny you pointed that out, as I saw the same thing in someone else's post and said the same thing to myself.  I at first figured it was "points" versus "pixels", which was why I tried to divide the position in half, which usually works.  But after doing that it was still way off.  It should not matter, but just in case it does, the sprites in question are being added as children of a tilemap (CCTMXTiledMap).